# Make resize image upon uploading of image using storeAs() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi how can I resize proportionally the image upon uploading of image? here's my upload code,

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::User();

    $folder = 'avatars';
    Storage::delete($folder.'/'.$user->avatar); 

    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.request()->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->avatar->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);

    $user->avatar = $avatarName;
    $user->save();

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

upon my digging, found this,

```
Image::make($files->getRealPath())->save($storagePath . '/' . $filename, 100)->resize(500, 500);
```

I only took the **->resize(xxx,xxx)** i did not use the whole code and i don't know where to put it. I tried though, but I can't make it work.

thanks!

Comment: Use this [package](http://image.intervention.io/) to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
Image::make($files->getRealPath())->resize(500, 500)->save($storagePath . '/' . $filename, 100);
```

If you want to put in your code then you might use like this.

```
        $avatar= $request->file('avatar');
        $thumbnailImage = Image::make($avatar);

        $storagePath = 'Your path will here';
        $myimage = $thumbnailImage->resize(500, 500);
        $myimage->save($storagePath . '/' .$user->id.'_avatar'.'.'.$avatar->getClientOriginalExtension());
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering! How can I incorporate that in my code?

Comment: it says,Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::make() must be of the type array, object given, called in